# Can np.abs take input array of dtype=[('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')] and give the absolute value?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to port some code from MATLAB to Python. MATLAB uses abs(data) to get absolute values for complex numbers in the data. I got that into an `ndarray(dim - (151402, 16, 64))` using the h5py module. This array contains real and imag values and I want to compute the absolute values for them. Numpy documentation suggests `np.abs` is the function for it but when used on this ndarray, I get this

```
error --> `numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'absolute' did 
not contain a loop with signature matching types 
dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')]) -> dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')])`.
```

Does this mean np.abs cannot compute absolute values for this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complex dtype array, `np.abs` produces the magnitude, as explained in its docs:

```
In [18]: x= np.array(1.1 - 0.2j)
In [19]: x
Out[19]: array(1.1-0.2j)
In [20]: x.dtype
Out[20]: dtype('complex128')
In [21]: np.abs(x)
Out[21]: 1.118033988749895
```

But you have constructed (or loaded) the complex array as a `structured array`, with separate `real` and `imag` fields.  `np.abs` isn't defined for such a `compound dtype`  (most calculations/ufunc don't work with structured arrays).

```
In [23]: dt = np.dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')])
In [24]: y = np.array((1.1, -0.2), dt)
In [25]: y
Out[25]: array((1.1, -0.2), dtype=[('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')])
In [26]: np.abs(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-26-e2973663f413>", line 1, in <module>
    np.abs(y)
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'absolute' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')]) -> dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')])
```

convert to complex dtype:

```
In [27]: np.abs(y['real']+y['imag']*1j)
Out[27]: 1.118033988749895
```

Alternatively we could use `view` to convert the dtype:

```
In [28]: y.view('complex')
Out[28]: array(1.1-0.2j)
In [29]: np.abs(y.view('complex'))
Out[29]: 1.118033988749895
```

`view` doesn't always work with compound dtypes, but here the underlying data byte layout is the same.

Comment: I'd need the structure as I've to separate the data into real and imag parts, before I pass it into downstream neural net. Is there a way I can do this and calculate the abs value?

Comment: I just showed how to get abs from the structured array.